# How to really delete all files in a folder and the folder on Windows using python?

Tags: python, windows, module, delete-file, shutil

this doesn’t delete the folder

```
shutil.rmtree('C:\\Users\\0\\Downloads\\preoutput')
```

this one causes this error
Message=[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\0\Downloads\testdelete'

```
import os
import glob

files = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\0\\Downloads\\preoutput')
for f in files:
    #os.chmod(f, 0o777)
    os.remove(f)
```

Comment: this should work, is see nothing wrong here. try running this python file as administrator and check permissions for that folder which users have the read write delete privilege.

Comment: Did you maybe have that folder open, for example in a console window? Or a file in the tree? Both of those situations would give *access denied*.

Comment: `glob` returns directories too but `os.remove` expect a file path.

Comment: no, the pythn code did change to another directory before doing it

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this program using shutil.rmtree()

```
import shutil
import os 

#location 
location = "C:\\Users\\0\\Downloads\\preoutput"
#directory 
dir = "preoutput"
#path 
path = os.path.join(location, dir) 
#removing directory 
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Comment: I believe that this answer advises OP to do pretty much what he tried and could not get to work.

Comment: full of errors https://ibb.co/3NJnNKP 
https://ibb.co/N6Zx2Zs

Comment: @RyanCase you should use double slash in path.

Comment: see second image